# Как правильно десериализовать json с помощью JSON.net в таблицу?

Tags: c#, json

Дан JSON.

> [{"PlayerName":"LeBron James","Team":"CLE","Score":22},{"PlayerName":"Kobe
>   Bryant","Team":"LAL","Score":3},{"PlayerName":"Chris
>   Paul","Team":"CLE","Score":7},{"PlayerName":"Pau
>   Gasol","Team":"CLE","Score":2},{"PlayerName":"Dirk
>   Nowitzki","Team":"LAL","Score":2},{"PlayerName":"Dwyane
>   Wade","Team":"CLE","Score":9},{"PlayerName":"Dwight
>   Howard","Team":"CLE","Score":20},{"PlayerName":"Tony
>   Parker","Team":"LAL","Score":10},{"PlayerName":"Andrey
>   Kirillenko","Team":"LAL","Score":11},{"PlayerName":"Vince
>   Carter","Team":"LAL","Score":27}]

Он содержит список игроков с указанием их команд и итогового количества набранных очков. Задача: получить с сервера JSON, десериализовать его и вывести его содержимое в форме таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Игроки должны быть отсортированы по количеству очков по убыванию.

Comment: В чем проблема? Берете либу с json.net, кормите строку json, получаете коллекцию игроков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JsonSort
{
    public class Player
    {
        public string PlayerName { get; set; }
        public string Team { get; set; }
        public int Score { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = @"
[
  {""PlayerName"":""LeBron James"",""Team"":""CLE"",""Score"":22},
  {""PlayerName"":""Kobe Bryant"",""Team"":""LAL"",""Score"":3},
  {""PlayerName"":""Chris Paul"",""Team"":""CLE"",""Score"":7},
  {""PlayerName"":""Pau Gasol"",""Team"":""CLE"",""Score"":2},
  {""PlayerName"":""Dirk Nowitzki"",""Team"":""LAL"",""Score"":2},
  {""PlayerName"":""Dwyane Wade"",""Team"":""CLE"",""Score"":9},
  {""PlayerName"":""Dwight Howard"",""Team"":""CLE"",""Score"":20},
  {""PlayerName"":""Tony Parker"",""Team"":""LAL"",""Score"":10},
  {""PlayerName"":""Andrey Kirillenko"",""Team"":""LAL"",""Score"":11},
  {""PlayerName"":""Vince Carter"",""Team"":""LAL"",""Score"":27}
]";
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Player>>(json).OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).ToList();

            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            data.ForEach(player =>
            {
                sb.AppendFormat(@"PlayerName: {0} Team: {1} Score: {2}{3}", player.PlayerName, player.Team, player.Score, Environment.NewLine);
            });
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Для работы примера вам потребуется библиотека `Newtonsoft.Json`. Ее можно подключить через `NuGet`

Comment: возникает исключение при использовании ReadKey: "Невозможно считывать клавиши, когда любое приложение не имеет консоли или ввод данных на консоли был переадресован из файла."

Comment: @AlexandraGolde у вас консольное приложение?

Comment: @МстиславПавлов а какой смысл определять класс Player, если данные просто выводятся в UI?

Comment: @МстиславПавлов да

Comment: @AlexandraGolde все же у меня есть подозрение, что у вас не консольное приложение. Консольное приложение создается так:  Файл -> Новый проект -> В списке выбираем Console Application (Консольное приложение)

Comment: @МстиславПавлов да, спасибо, все работает

Comment: @AlexandraGolde если вам по данному вопросу больше не требуется помощь, то нажмите галочку напротив моего ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Получить JSON с сервера можно так

```
var c = new System.Net.WebClient();
var json = c.DownloadString(url);
```

---

Распарсить, отсортировать и вывести в виде таблицы

```
// #r "\Newtonsoft.Json\6.0.3\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\json.txt");
var tbl = JArray.Parse(json)
                .Select(j => new {
                               PlayerName = j["PlayerName"],
                               Team = j["Team"],
                               Score = j["Score"] 
                               }); 
foreach(var v in tbl.OrderByDescending(i => i.Score))
   Console.WriteLine(v.PlayerName + "\t" + v.Team + "\t" + v.Score);
```

Результат

```
Vince Carter      LAL 27
LeBron James      CLE 22
Dwight Howard     CLE 20
Andrey Kirillenko LAL 11
Tony Parker       LAL 10
Dwyane Wade       CLE 9
Chris Paul        CLE 7
Kobe Bryant       LAL 3
Pau Gasol         CLE 2
Dirk Nowitzki     LAL 2
```

---